# asp.net - TypeLoadException when calling Profile.GetProfile(user.UserName) for MySQLProfileProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mysql

I need to store some data related to single user so I decide to use `Profile` with custom property. When I want to access any of static methods in `Profile` property I am getting `ConfigurationErrorException` and inner exception is `TypeLoadException`.

During debugging I have checked in `Modules` view that `MySql.Web.dll` is loaded, and in reflector I am able to see type `MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider`, I am guessing that it can be some security issue but I don't known if this is true and how to deal with that.

Here is my `Web.Config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="server=localhost;User Id=ID;Password=PASS;database=users" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0" debug="true">
    </compilation>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
             autogenerateschema="true"
             type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D" 
             applicationName="/" 
             connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" 
             writeExceptionsToEventLog="False" 
             passwordFormat="Clear" 
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
             minRequiredPasswordLength="6">
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile enabled ="true" defaultProvider="MySQLProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="MySQLProfileProvider" 
             type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider , MySql.Web, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D" 
             connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
      <properties>
        <add name="UserIdData" type="System.String"/>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="KolorprintAspNetSqlRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="KolorprintAspNetSqlRoleProvider" 
             type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"
             connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" 
             applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <trust level="High" />
    <identity impersonate="false"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

In code there is normal acces to "Profile", also Roles and Membership is working normally.

Does anyone here have any idea what might be going on and/or how to fix this problem?

Comment: I can't take the credit for somebody else's solution, but this might help you: http://jeremeguenther.blogspot.co.il/2009/01/nunit-error-could-not-load-type.html